# Using ColdFusion and getting "Internal Server Error" instead of ColdFusion error page

Tags: coldfusion, error-handling

I'm using IIS7 with Windows Server2008 R2. I have ColdFusion 11 set up and running. Everything seems to work fine except whenever I have a coldfusion error, I get an error message from IIS instead of ColdFusion. I get the generic 500 - Internal Server Error instead of the ColdFusion page telling me what is wrong.

This is a new installation on an empty server. Nothing else is running on this machine and nothing else has been loaded.

In the ColdFusion Administrator I have the check boxes for "Enable Robust Exception Information" and  "Enable Request Debugging Output" checked.

If there are no errors on the page, the page works fine. Its just hard to debug when I can't see what's wrong if there is a typo or something.

Thanks.

Comment: Check your exception logs.  When I see what you describe, I usually see a java heap space error in the log.

Comment: Check the admin there is a setting to set http status codes so IIS sees that and displays it's error page.

Comment: Possibly "friendly error" messages set for your browser.  Are you using IE?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807

Comment: @SeanCoyne, I don't see any options like this. Can you tell me specifically which one you are talking about.

Comment: @GerryGurevich, It's not browser specific, it happens in all browsers.

Comment: "Enable HTTP Status Codes" http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffc.html

Comment: I think there is a setting in IIS to disable it taking over errors somewhere

Comment: @SeanCoyne, that was it. Thanks. If you want to post as answer, I can accept it. That solved the problem. It's under "Server Settings" >> "Settings".

Answer (score 7):

Check your "enable http status codes" setting under server settings > settings in the CF administrator. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffc.html

When CF sets a 500 status code on error IIS sees this and responds with its error page.

While unchecking this option will technically solve your issue the real solution would be to modify IIS' settings so that it serves up your desired error page. You shouldn't be sending coldfusion's error pages to users on a production site.